# block character input in script .bat

Tags: windows, batch-file

I have the script below and just want numbers to be entered, but if the user enters with special characters the system does not make the proper treatment
(ex: ", @,!)

Any ideas on how I can block and accept only numbers?`

```
@echo off
cls
:menu
cls

color 80

date /t
time /t
echo.

echo Computador: %computername%        Usuario logado: %username%
echo.           
echo IMPORTANTE: EXECUTAR ESSE SCRIPT SOMENTE NESTE SERVIDOR
echo.
echo  ==================================
echo * 1. TROCAR SENHAS DOS SERVERS     *
echo * 2. DETALHES SOBRE O HARDWARE     *
echo * 3. DETALHES SOBRE OS DISCOS      *
echo * 4. SAIR                          * 
echo  ==================================
echo.

set /p opcao= ESCOLHA UMA DAS OPCOES: 
echo ------------------------------
echo ------------------------------
if %opcao% equ 1 goto opcao1
if %opcao% equ 2 goto opcao2
if %opcao% equ 3 goto opcao3
if %opcao% equ 4 goto opcao4
if %opcao% GEQ 5 goto opcao5
```

Comment: Instead of `set /p`, use the correct command, `choice`! e.g. `"%__AppDir__%choice.exe" /C 1234 /N /M "ESCOLHA UMA DAS OPCOES:"`, then you can use `GoTo opcao%ErrorLevel% 2>NUL||GoTo opcao5`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you can count the number of characters in the string, and also use echo in unicode, it is possible to apply a filter to get only the numbers in the variable "option".
Thus, you can check if the number of occurrences of numbers in the string is equal to the length of the option variable.
If equal, input ok, else, goto menu.

```bat
@echo off && setlocal enabledelayedexpansion & break off

cls & title <nul & title [%computername%] ...\%~nx0
set _msg_erro=-^> Input invalido, pressione qualquer tecla para continuar
set _msg_zok=-^> Pressione qualquer tecla para continuar

:menu
cls && echo/ && color 80 && for /f "tokens=2delims==." %%i in ('
wmic OS Get localdatetime /value ^|findstr /r [0-9] ')do set "_dt=%%i %time:~0,5%"
echo.
echo.
echo/ Computador: [%computername%]  -^|^|-  Usuario logado: [%username%]
echo.           
echo/ IMPORTANTE: EXECUTAR ESSE SCRIPT SOMENTE NESTE SERVIDOR^^!
echo.
echo/  ==================================
echo/ * 1. TROCAR SENHAS DOS SERVERS     *
echo/ * 2. DETALHES SOBRE O HARDWARE     *
echo/ * 3. DETALHES SOBRE OS DISCOS      *
echo/ * 4. SAIR                          *
echo/  ==================================
echo.

set /p "input=| %_dt:~6,2%/%_dt:~4,2%/%_dt:~0,4% %time:~0,5% | ESCOLHA UMA DAS OPCOES: "
echo/ ----------------------------------------------------- 
if "!input!"=="" (
    %__appdir__%rundll32.exe %__appdir__%cmdext.dll,MessageBeepStub
    echo/Nenhuma opcao escolida, pressione qualquer tecla para continuar^^!
    timeout -1 >nul & goto :menu
  ) else (set "opcao=!input!" && set input=<nul && call :test_number "!opcao!"
    !_do! && echo/ [%username%] escolheu opcao: !opcao! )

echo/ ----------------------------------------------------- 
for /l %%L in (1 1 4)do if "%%L"=="!opcao!" goto :opcao%%~L
timeout -1 >nul & endlocal & goto :EOF


:opcao1
echo/ Label here == opcao!opcao!
echo/ !_msg_zok! timeout -1 >nul & endlocal & exit /b 0

:opcao2
echo/ Label here == opcao!opcao!
echo/ !_msg_zok! timeout -1 >nul & endlocal & exit /b 0

:opcao3
echo/ Label here == opcao!opcao!
echo/ !_msg_zok! timeout -1 >nul & endlocal & exit /b 0

:opcao4
echo/ Label here == opcao!opcao!
echo/ !_msg_zok! timeout -1 >nul & endlocal & exit /b 0

:test_number
set "_str=%~1"
for /f %%h in ('cmd /u/c set /p "=%_str:"=%"^<nul^|find /v /c ""
')do set "_str_len=%%h" && for /f %%i in ('
cmd /u/c set /p "=%_str:"=%"^<nul^|find /v " "^|findstr [0-9]^|find /v /c " "
')do set "_num=%%i"

if !_str_len! neq !_num! (
   set _num=<nul && set _str_len=<nul && set _str=<nul
   %__appdir__%rundll32.exe %__appdir__%cmdext.dll,MessageBeepStub
   echo/!_msg_erro! && timeout -1 >nul & set "_do=goto :menu"
   ) else set "_do=rem./" && exit /b
```

<sub>Sorry my limited **English**</sub>

Comment: This code performs the same action as **`choice`** command, but, it also goes  echoing in the output the invalid string typed by the user.

Answer (score 0):

As per my comment, you should use the `Choice` command instead of `Set /P`:

```bat
@Echo Off

:Menu
ClS
Color 80
Date /T
Time /T
Echo(
Echo Computador: %ComputerName%        Usuario logado: %UserName%
Echo(           
Echo IMPORTANTE: EXECUTAR ESSE SCRIPT SOMENTE NESTE SERVIDOR
Echo(
Echo  ==================================
Echo * 1. TROCAR SENHAS DOS SERVERS     *
Echo * 2. DETALHES SOBRE O HARDWARE     *
Echo * 3. DETALHES SOBRE OS DISCOS      *
Echo * 4. SAIR                          * 
Echo  ==================================
Echo(
"%__AppDir__%choice.exe" /C 1234 /N /M "ESCOLHA UMA DAS OPCOES:"
GoTo opcao%ErrorLevel% 2>NUL||GoTo opcao5
```

Alternatively, with delayed expansion enabled, you can continue using `Set /P` and check the input using a `Findstr.exe` match:

```bat
@Echo Off
SetLocal EnableDelayedExpansion

:Menu
ClS
Color 80
Date /T
Time /T
Echo(
Echo Computador: %ComputerName%        Usuario logado: %UserName%
Echo(           
Echo IMPORTANTE: EXECUTAR ESSE SCRIPT SOMENTE NESTE SERVIDOR
Echo(
Echo  ==================================
Echo * 1. TROCAR SENHAS DOS SERVERS     *
Echo * 2. DETALHES SOBRE O HARDWARE     *
Echo * 3. DETALHES SOBRE OS DISCOS      *
Echo * 4. SAIR                          * 
Echo  ==================================
Echo(
Set /P "opcao= ESCOLHA UMA DAS OPCOES: "
Echo "!opcao:~1!"|"%__AppDir__%findstr.exe" "^\"[1-4]\"$">NUL&&(
    GoTo opcao!opcao:~1!)||GoTo opcao5
```